# XCLASS - Fatal error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using TYPO3 6.2 and I want to extend an existing extension using XCLASS. The existing extension has the namespace A. The XCLASSes come from the namspace B. The following code defines some classes and methods that will be overwritten:

```
namespace A;

class Class1 {
    protected function func1(\A\Class2 obj) {
        //do something
    }
}

class Class2 {...}

namespace B;

class ux_Class1 extends \A\Class1 {
    protected function func1(\A\Class2 obj) {
        parent::func1(obj);
        obj->func2();
    }
}

class ux_Class2 extends \A\Class2 {
    protected function func2() {
        //do something
    }
}

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['A\\Class1'] = array('className' => 'B\\ux_Class1');
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['A\\Class2'] = array('className' => 'B\\ux_Class2');
```

But I get the  following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method A\Class2::func2() in
>   B/ux_Class1.php on line 6

Why is this happening? Should't B\ux_Class2::func2() be called instead because of overwriting with XCLASS?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how `A\Class2` is being instantiated. If it was done using `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()` instead of `new A\Class2()` it should work. The `ux_` prefix is not required anymore in newer TYPO3 versions.

If the class is used in an **Extbase** context, most instantiations are handled using `ObjectManager`. In that regard, one has to register alternative implementations either directly in e.g. `ext_localconf.php` or via TypoScript.

### ext_localconf.php

```
/** @var $extbaseObjectContainer \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container */
$extbaseObjectContainer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container::class
);
$extbaseObjectContainer->registerImplementation(
    \A\Class2::class,
    \B\Class2::class
);
```

### Front-end TypoScript

```
config.tx_extbase {
    objects {
        A\Class2 {
            className = B\Class2
        }
    }
}
```